# Audire, with accusative or dative?

Tags: accusative, dative

The verb [audire](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/audio#Latin) is many times (if not most of the times) found with an accusative. For example, in the Vulgata, [4 Regum, 22:11](http://www.drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=12&ch=22&l=11-#x) says:

> et audisset rex **verba** libri legis Domini, scidit vestimenta sua.

Yet, sometimes it appears with a dative. For example, [4 Regum, 22:19](http://www.drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=12&ch=22&l=19-#x):

> et perterritum est cor tuum, et humiliatus es coram Domino, auditis **sermonibus** contra locum istum, et habitatores ejus, quod videlicet fierent in stuporem et in maledictum ...

Now, *audire* can mean "to hear" or "to listen to". Is this distinction between accusative and dative used to stress precisely the meaning of the verb, as we would do in English by using either "to hear [someone/something]" or "to listen to [someone/something]"? Is there some profound distinction between the two forms of the verb?

By my superficial research, it seems there is no major distinction. For instance, [L&S](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=audio) state:

> C. *To hear, to listen to, to obey, heed*; orig. and class. only with acc., but also with dat.

Is this the case?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually, your quote from the Vulgate *isn't* an example of *audire* + dative! Though *auditis* is spelled the same as the present 2nd person plural ("You [pl.] hear"), it is actually an ablative perfect participle. A clue to this is that there would be an unexplained shift from *tu* to *vos*.

In your sentence, *auditis sermonibus* is an ablative absolute forming a distinct unit. The sentence can be roughly translated as:

> And your heart was terrified, and you were brought low before the Lord, once you heard the words (literally: "with the speeches having been heard") against this place and its inhabitants, namely that they would become stricken and accursed.

By a strange coincidence, though, there *are* cases where *audire* can take the dative, though (as the referenced L&S entry makes clear) these aren't common. Based on the examples supplied in L&S, it appears that this dative object is only used when *audire* means "obey" or "pay heed to" (not simply: "hear"). Though I don't have a corpus search available, the vast majority of examples seem to employ the idiom "dicto audiens esse" (= "to be true to one's word").

Since there appears to be disputed manuscript evidence in the Cicero quote, and the only other reference that *doesn't* use this idiom is from Appuleius (2nd c. AD), I would be comfortable saying that you should avoid any usage of the dative besides that idiom.