# Is "mihi audi!" incorrect?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, case, imperative

I'm currently doing Latin in high school, and there's one thing which I can't get my head around in a recent test I got back.

I translated the command *"Listen to me!"* as *"mihi audi!"* but it was marked as wrong, and the correct answer (according to my teacher) was *"me audi!"*.

Why isn't the dative (*mihi*) used here? Doesn't it literally mean "Listen to me", or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Welcome to the site and thanks for posting your question!

Comment: literal translations don't 100% work

Comment: Related: https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/12505/audire-with-accusative-or-dative

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your match of *mihi* with "to" is correct, but that's the dative case, not the genitive. The genitive is *mei*.

Neither case is appropriate here, though. *Audio* more or less contains the idea of "to" in itself—it means "hear" or "listen to". Thus

> Listen to me!

becomes

> (Listen to) (me)!

becomes

> Audi me!

Another way of saying "Listen to me" could be "Hear me". In that rephrasing, the reason for using accusative is more obvious.

If you wanted a word that more closely meant "listen to" rather than "hear", a word that didn't have that sort of passive undertone, you could use *ausculto*.

Answer (score 3):

As a matter of fact, audire, in the sense “listen to, obey”, can be construed with a dative, or indeed two datives, in the idiom “dicto audientem esse alicui”, literally “to be listening to the word to someone”, that is: “to obey someone”.

So for “listen to me!” you could say “dicto audiens es mihi”.

See here (towards the end): https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Daudio